# Is it possible to use KIARA Middleware to make a SOAP RPC Call?

Tags: http, soap, middleware, fiware

I was interested in using Kiara middleware for fiware, but i can only make rpc requests for Kiara created server. Is it possible to extend the client so it can make a SOAP Request? In the GE specification it says REST and SOAP must be supported for a middleware.

Answer (score 0):

KIARA does not support REST, neither SOAP, the paradigm is really different. We supported a year ago some degree of compatibility in a previous release, but it was complex to understand and use, so we discarded the feature. KIARA is designed focusing in performance, and REST is really heavyweight. What is your use case?

Jaime Martin Losa.- KIARA Team Leader.

Comment: I need to access a Web Service to get data and store it in a Orion Context Broker, but the point is keep using Fi-ware related GE's and not develop a middleware from scratch. Thanks for the info anyway!